# R.java auto generated file

Tags: android, r.java-file

In android 2.1 & 2.2 R.java file is auto-generated. But in 2.0 platform we have to built R.java file. anyone know how to generate R.java file from program.

Comment: Not true. R is always auto-generated. Try cleaning your project.

Answer (score 3):

Use clean and build in eclipse, R.java is "Generated" every time when you build your android project.