# My R.java file has disappeared, nothing works

Tags: android, r.java-file

After change some resources (Images) manually my R.java file has disappeared. I've tried all, I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516428/r-java-auto-generated-file), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603217/r-java-deleted-automatically-android), and a lot of entries, but nothing works for me.
I have revised all my Layouts and resources, but apparently any layout hasn't problems.
Is possible to export all my project and build another? Or without the R.java class I've nothing to do?  thanks a lot!

**I've solved it!** I deleted the last files added and I restarted eclipsed, right now all is working correctly

Comment: How have you named the images? Are  you sure the image names are legal?

Comment: Absolutely sure, before change the image all was perfectly, and really I substituted an image by another with the same name, so I haven't added any new resource.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse to build?

Comment: Also check that your manifest file doesnt refer to non-existing images or other files

Comment: When I try to rebuild the project, the console throws this:
[2012-12-19 19:14:32 - andtest] R.java was removed! Recreating R.java!
But nothing changes after this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your problems tab for errors within the /res/ folder?
If there is something wrong with any of your resource files then the R file will not be generated.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your Console output.  You probably have an illegally named file and have a message similar to --

> ```
> Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]
> ```

Comment: No, only appears this: When I try to rebuild the project, the console throws this:
[2012-12-19 19:14:32 - andtest] R.java was removed! Recreating R.java!
But nothing changes after this.

Comment: The next suspect would be an error in one of the xml files.  Do Project > Clean and then look in the "Problems" view for xml errors.  Also, on older versions of the ADT, you can get <filename>.xml.out files which interfere with compilation.  You can remove these, they can be created by mistake by pressing the run or build buttons when you are editing an xml file.